# Why the function returns None?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to print the **Fibonacci series** by **recursion**. But that return **None** at the end every time and to print function as well.

Tried putting else condition as well, but couldn't figure out what to return if I want to end the program there.

I did search on the SO, found some solutions but didn't work for me.

Help me with this. Also tell me which concept I am failing to understand.

```
def Fibonacii(a,b,n):
    if(n>=1):
        sum=a+b
        a=b
        b=sum
        return Fibonacii(a,b,n-1)

def main():
    a=0 
    b=1
    n=10
    print(Fibonacii(a,b,n-2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have no base case; what should `Fibonacii` return when `n < 1`?

Comment: If `n=1`, then you end up returning `Fibonacii(a, b, 0)`, which will return `None`.  You should come up with a base case.

Comment: You print a function that already prints. Just call Fibonacii without print.

Comment: BTW, `sum` is not a good variable name because it shadows the built-in `sum` function.

Comment: @Kefeng91 Tried that, but at the end it's showing just None

Comment: What do you expect or intend `Fibonacii(a, b, 0)` to return?

Comment: However, if `Fibonacii` is *outputing* each number, rather than returning a list, you don't need to print the (irrelevant) return value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got your point. But what should I return in else condition as I want to end the program if it reaches there

Comment: @SHubHam, No, you don't want to end the program, you just want to stop recursing deeper and return control to the parent copies of the function in outer stack frames. `return 0` will suffice.

Comment: Fibonacci(0) is 0, but if you pass `n=0` to your function it skips over the `if` block, and returns the default return value, which is `None`. And `None` is not a number so if you try to do arithmetic on it you get an error. So when your function gets `n=0` it needs to return 0. And that will allow the recursion to work correctly.

Comment: @PM2Ring But then my print function prints **None** and not the Fibonacci Number

Comment: @SHubHam I'll say it again: your function already calls `print` *inside* the function; there is no need to print its return value. Just call the function. If you want it to build a list of Fibonacci numbers to return, that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you don't handle the case when `n < 1`, i.e. the *base-case*. This is a solution working in linear space with `n` calls to the `fibonacci_helper()` function if you want to stick with *recursive functions*.

```
def fibonacci_helper(a, b, n):
    if n == 0:
        return (a, b)
    return fibonacci_helper(b, a+b, n-1)

def fibonacci(n):
    return fibonacci_helper(0, 1, n)[0]

print([fibonacci(i) for i in range(10)])
# prints '[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]'
```

If you want a more efficient solution using constant space in memory, the one proposed by @chepner certainly suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is irrelevant, as your function is printing each number as it is generated.

```
def Fibonacii(a, b, n):
    if(n>=1):
        sum=a+b
        a=b
        b=sum
        print(sum)
        Fibonacii(a, b, n-1)

Fibonacii(0, 1, 10)
```

Recursion isn't a good way to iterate in Python, however. An explicit loop uses constant space, rather than using memory proportional to `n`:

```
def Fib(a, b, n):
    while n > 0:
        a, b = b, a + b  # No temporary variable necessary
        print(b)
        n -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I want it to be done using recursion only.

Comment: Then you should use a different language.